# Is $cD_{\epsilon}(z_0)$ a subset of $D_{|c|\epsilon}(cz_{0})$ where $c$ is a non-zero complex number?

Tags: complex-analysis

If we take the open disc centred at $z_0$ with radius $\epsilon$ and multiply every element in it by the non-zero complex number $c$ i.e. $cD_{\epsilon}(z_0)$, is this a subset of the open disc with radius |c|\epsilon and centred at $cz_{0}$ i.e. $D_{|c|\epsilon}(cz_{0})$?

In short is $cD_{\epsilon}(z_0) \subseteq D_{|c|\epsilon}(cz_{0})$?

My intuition so far is to consider multiplication of a disc area on $\mathbb{C}$ by a complex number $c$ as transforming the area into an ellipse, and then trying to show the radius of the semi-major axis is smaller than $|c|\epsilon$, meaning this new ellipse can fit insite the disc of radius $|c|\epsilon$ hence it is a subset.

Answer (score 1):

If $z\in cD_\varepsilon(z_0)$, then $z=c\times w$, for some $w\in D_\varepsilon(z_0)$. But then$$|z-cz_0|=|cw-cz_0|=|c||w-z_0|<|c|\varepsilon.$$And actually $cD_\varepsilon(z_0)\color{red}=D_{|c|\varepsilon}(cz_0)$.

Answer (score 1):

Notice that for any complex number $c\neq0$ and ball $D_\varepsilon(0)$ of radius $\varepsilon>0$ around the origin
$$cD_\varepsilon(0)=\{cz:|z|<\varepsilon\}=\{w:|w|<|c|\varepsilon\}=D_{|c|\varepsilon}(0)$$

From
$$z_0+D_\varepsilon(0):=\{z_0+z:|z|<\varepsilon\}=\{w:|w-z_0|<\varepsilon\}=D_\varepsilon(z_0),$$
it follows that
\begin{align}
c D_\varepsilon(z_0)&=c\big(z_0+D_\varepsilon(z_0)\Big)=cz_0+cD_\varepsilon(z_0)\\
&=cz_0+D_{|c|\varepsilon}(0)=D_{|c|\varepsilon}(cz_0)
\end{align}

For $c=0$, $cD_\varepsilon(z_0)=\{0\}$ while $D_{|c|\varepsilon}(w)=\emptyset$ for all $w\in\mathbb{C}$. Hence, for $c=0$
$$cD_\varepsilon(z_0)=\{0\}\supset D_{|c|\varepsilon}(cz_0)=\emptyset$$

Answer (score 1):

I suspect this question was prompted by my comment on your
[previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4632291/if-we-have-an-open-set-s-and-multiply-every-element-of-s-by-a-fixed-complex) where I noted that the image of a circle under multiplication by a fixed nonzero complex number would be an ellipse since that operation is a rotation and a scaling.

I didn't think far enough ahead. Clearly that image is itself a circle since the expansion of the complex plane by a constant factor scales the same way in all directions, so circles map to circles. You don't need algebra to show that the regions you ask about are equal.